# Nested functions: "Error: Could not find nested function"

Tags: r, nested-function

I am defining a function which has nested functions, like the following:

```
 afunc <- function(p1, p2) { 

 for loop {
   f = bfunc(p1)
 }
 g = cfunc(p2)

 bfunc <- function(p3) {
   ...
 }

 cfunc <-function(p4){
  ...
 }

}
```

For some reason, I am getting "ERROR: Could not find function "bfunc"". Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your function definition to before where it executes:

```
afunc <- function(p1, p2) { 
 bfunc <- function(p3) {
   ...
 }

 cfunc <-function(p4){
  ...
 }

 for loop {
   f = bfunc(p1)
 }
 g = cfunc(p2)


}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Just had to adopt my code from Matlab to R. And hence, the confusion. thanks.